# Horizontal navigation to vertical responsive navigation, responsive navigation top level has too much height and last next level navigation disappears

Tags: css, navigation

I have converted a horizontal navigation to vertical responsive navigation, but when you open the responsive navigation top level (ul li) by klicking on 'Menu', ul li has too much height (see the gray area underneath the top level) and the last menue point in the next level disappears 
(Menu 1 should have 7 sub level menue points ul li ul li a's, Menu 2 should have 5 and Menu 3 should have 3) .

I figured it out that is has to do with the following CSS from the desktop version but don't know how to get rid of the problem:

```
            ul.topNav li ul {
            display: none;
            **position: absolute;
            top: 2.3rem;**
            background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
        }
```

Tried a lot but nothing worked out. Below you find all code and the link to make it run and see the result. Don't forget to resize your window between 320 and 979px and maybe reload to be sure it works.

```js
function init() {

                var ww = document.body.clientWidth;
                var mobileLayout = ww <= 1024;

                if (mobileLayout) {
                    /* show topNav */
                    $("#menuIcon").click(function () {
                        $("#topNavResp").fadeToggle(100);
                        });
                        /* show topNav second level and close all others */
                        $('.topNavLi').on('click', function (event) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();

                            $(this).parent().siblings().children().next().slideUp();
                            return false;
                        });

                    } else {
                        alert('please reduce/shrink your window and reload');
                    }
                }
```

```css
            html {
                font-size: 15px;
                background-color: rgba(227, 227, 227, 1);
            }
            ol, ul, li {
                list-style-type: none;
            }
            a {
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            /* ------------------- TOP NAV BAR ------------------------------------------ */

            #headerNavBar {
                width: 100%;
                height: 2.4rem;
                line-height: 2.4rem;
                display: block;
                background-color: #D3D3D3;
                *zoom: 1;
            }

            ul.topNav {
                float: right;
                width: 75%;
                height: 2.3rem;
                position: relative;
                z-index: 10;
            }
            ul.topNav > li {
                line-height: 2.3rem;
                float: left;
                width: auto;
                position: relative;
            }

            ul.topNav li a.topNavLi {
                height: 2.3rem;
                float: left;
                padding: 0 10.3%;
            }
            ul.topNav li a:hover.topNavLi,
            ul.topNav li:active a.topNavLi,
            ul.topNav li:hover a.topNavLi {
                    border-bottom: 0.13rem solid #e23427;
                    color: #e23427;
            }

            /* ------------------- TOP NAV 2nd LEVEL------------------------------------- */

            ul.topNav li ul {
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
                top: 2.3rem;
                background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
            }
            ul.topNav li ul li {
                float: none;
                display: block;
            }
            ul.topNav li ul li a {
                display: block;
                color: #231f20;
            }
            ul.topNav li ul li:hover,
            ul.topNav li ul li:active {
                    background-color: rgb(227, 33, 33);
            }
            ul.topNav li ul li:hover a,
            ul.topNav li ul li:active a {
                    color: #fff;
            }
            /**************************************************************************** */
            /**************************************************************************** */
            @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 979px)
            {
                body {
                    width: 95%;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                }
                #wrapper {
                    width: 100%;
                }    
                #pageHead {
                    width: 100%;
                }

                /* ------------------- NAVI Responsive  --------------------------------- */
                #headerNavBar {
                    height: 2.9rem;
                    line-height: 2.9rem;
                    position: relative;
                }

                #menuIcon {
                    display: block;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    right: 0;
                    padding: 0.3rem 1rem 0 0;
                }         
                ul.topNav {
                    display: none;
                    float: none;
                    width: 100%;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 2.9rem;
                }
                .topNav > li {
                    width: 100% !important;
                    background-color: #D3D3D3;
                    display: block;
                    position: static;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
                }
                ul#topNavResp.topNav li a.topNavLi,
                ul#topNavResp.topNav li ul li a {
                    width: 100%;
                }
                ul.topNav li a:hover.topNavLi,
                ul.topNav li:active a.topNavLi,
                ul.topNav li:hover a.topNavLi {
                border: none;
                }
            /* ------------------- TOP NAV Responsive 2nd LEVEL ------------------------- */
                ul.topNav li ul {
                    display: none;
                    width: 100%;
                    position: static;
                    padding-left: 10.3%;
                    background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
                }
                ul.topNav li ul li {
                    width: 100%;
                }
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init();">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="pageHead">

                <nav id="headerNavBar">                 

                    <a href="#" id="menuIcon">MENU</a>
                 

                    <ul class="topNav" id="topNavResp">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="topNavLi">Menu 1</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">11111</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">22222</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">33333</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">44444</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">55555</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">66666</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">77777</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li> 
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="topNavLi">Menu 2</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">11111</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">22222</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">33333</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">44444</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">55555</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li> 
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="topNavLi">Menu 3</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">11111</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">22222</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">33333</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </nav><!-- end topNav -->
            </div>
 
        </div><!-- end wrapper -->

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the rule:

`@media only screen and (max-width: 979px) and (min-width: 320px){
    ul.topNav li ul {
        ...
        position: inherit;
    }
}`

To:

`@media only screen and (max-width: 979px) and (min-width: 320px){
    ul.topNav li ul {
        ...
        position: static;
    }
}`

Comment: Hi Douglas! :-)  Thanks for that hint!! It solved the problem a bit. I added some more colors (like in the original) to show up the problem that we have now:  now the first level seems to be almost correct - it's still 'loosing' the background-color when 'active' - but the first sublevel menue entry is too high and overlays/covers the first level navigation entry.

Comment: One thing solved: The first sublevel menue entry now was too high and overlaid/covered the first level navigation entry. I added  the following:           ul.topNav li ul li {
/*new*/              height: auto;
/*new*/                overflow: hidden;
            }   But how can I keep the background-color of the first level menu entry?

Comment: Hi, the first problem is solved with `float: none`. ul#topNavResp.topNav li a.topNavLi, ul#topNavResp.topNav li ul li a { `float: none` }. But, to keep the background without :hover, it will be necessary use something like input radio or checkbox, (without JS). See: http://codepen.io/CesarGabriel/pen/tLDwH